# Activity not finishing

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a `DialogFragment` that includes a `DatePickerDialog`. Whenever I set the date, a new activity gets started. When I press back it goes back to the same activity. Why doesn't the activity finish?

In the activity I start the dialog in the following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.calendar:
            new ViewCalendar().show(getFragmentManager(), "Calendar");
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have the following in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int y, int m, int d) {
    c.set(y, m, d);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Calendar.class);
    getActivity().finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

EDIT:

I am going to describe the problem a bit more.

I have an activity A with a button that starts a `DatePickerDialog`. I select a date and the following should happen:

- Activity A gets finished.
- New instance of Activity A created.

What is happening now is:

- Activity A stays at background.
- New instance of Activity A created.

The stack of activities is now A - A, that's why if I press back it goes back to the older instance.

Comment: your order is wrong you should first start activity and then finish the current activity like `startActivity(i);
    getActivity().finish();`

Comment: change Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Calendar.class);
    
    startActivity(intent);                                                         getActivity().finish();

Comment: Are you getting the right Activity with getActivity() ?

Comment: @Mert how do I check for that?

Comment: Get The class of it and show by debugging if its the right one: getActivity().getClass()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your Back stack is not clear, that is the reason your previous activity is open while on 
back press. So clear your Back stack properly, it will work perfectly.

Apply this code :

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int y, int m, int d) {
    c.set(y, m, d);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Calendar.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

Comment: Not really the solution. When the new activity is started, the older one must be finished.

Comment: Actually, your are finished your activity but your history not clear so if your click back button your activity is restart. so apply this line your code : yourIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: It it working now. So the old activity was restarting?

Comment: yes. if you no need back stack clear properly. it will work properly.

Comment: Overriding `onBackPressed()` the way you did is useless. The default implementation of `onBackPressed()` already calls `finish()`. You should remove this from your answer as it is unnecessary and confusing. Also, if you are starting an Activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, it isn't necessary to call `finish()` on your own activity, as Android will finish it for you.

Answer (score 0):

use getActivity().this.finish(); instead of getActivity().finish();

Comment: I wish there was some explanation as to why you think there is a difference between the two statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should first start the intent and then finish the current activity.

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int y, int m, int d) {
    c.set(y, m, d);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Calendar.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

Comment: if you want to kill your activity in back press. override your OnBackPressed method: